# problem with behavior trigger, doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm working with this database ... basically I have to create a "promote_cyclist" trigger, to memorize the eligible athletes (who are ranked first on a stage of the Giro d'Italia) in the mesh table.

The tables are:

- cyclist (cyclist_id: Int, name_cyclist: string, team: string of three letters, country: three-letter string)
- tape (_name: string, km: int, type: 'flat' or 'high_mountain' or 'medium_mountain' or 'chronometro_a_team' or 'chronometro_individual' or 'time_trial')
- arrival_order (cyclist_id:int ; tape_name:string, order: int): where cyclist_id (resp, tape_name) is an external key that refers to cyclist (resp, tape);
- magliarosa( name:string );

this is the trigger I load on the shell ...

```
CREATE FUNCTION promote_cyclist()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO magliarosa
        SELECT c.name_cyclist
        FROM cyclist c
        WHERE new.cyclist_id = c.cyclist_id AND
              new.order = 1;
RETURN NULL;
END ;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is the command I pass to the shell:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER promote_cyclist
 BEFORE INSERT ON arrival_order
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE promote_cyclist ();
```

After having uploaded the arrival_order txt file, the names of the cyclists who have won at least one stage should be recorded on the names in magliarosa. This however does not happen. Could you please help me?

Comment: you miss clause `FOR EACH ROW` in `CREATE TRIGGER` statement

Answer (score 1):

You created a BEFORE TRIGGER so it fires before the INSERT really happens. But RETURN NULL tells the database to replace the NEW payload with NULL.

Try RETURN NEW;

Comment: thanks, I added "for each row" and changed the return ... now the tuples are inserted in 'Magliarosa' but it can happen that if a cyclist wins more than one stage, his name is present several times in 'Magliarosa'. ... I thought that with a simple 'SELECT DISTINCT c.cyclist_name' in the 'promote_cyclist' function was enough but it is not so ... how can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: When a name should be there just once, I would use a unique constraint and make sure the insert will check for conflicts: ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

Comment: ok, so basically next to 'name' I put 'UNIQUE' .... 'ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING' where should I write it?

Comment: Yes, the UNIQUE constraint can be created when you create the table, create a unique index or create a separate unique constraint. All three will work fine. The ON CONFLICT is described in the manual and showing some examples: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Comment: From what I understand it should be used with 'Insert' but I don't use this command to insert tuples ... I use copy ... what should I do?

Comment: I think I would change my code to use INSERT instead of COPY. Especially because I won't expect that many athletes and I wouldn't be worried about the performance difference between COPY and INSERT. But that's just my first impression about your situation without knowing all the details.